# Display times for different Australian States

Tags: php, time, clock

We use very simple php function to display time and date.

```
<div class="datedata"><?=date("l, F jS, Y", time());?></div>
```

But I was thinking how would I display the actual time in differennt Australian States.

I used to know the script for displaying the time of our server, which is in nsw but forgot it. Guess that would be easiest.. display server time and then show diff times based on server time + / - 1 hr whatever...

Wonder if anyones got any suggestions..
Cheers

With @crolpa help this is what I have, like i said .. im crap with php.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Adelaide');
$adelaide = time();

date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
$melbourne = time();

date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');
$sydney = time();

//etc...

?>

<?=date("G:i a",$adelaide)?><br />
<?=date("G:i a",$melbourne)?><br />
<?=date("G:i a",$sydney)?><br />
```

Comment: Out of curiosity does Oz have daylight saving time?

Comment: We do but QLD doesnt observe it, nor does WA I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the offsets to the base time. So..

```
$offset = 3600 * 1.5 //+ 1.5 hours

$timestamp = time() + $offset;

echo date("l, F jS, Y",$timestamp);
```

The default `time()` function is set by your server. You can change this easily with at the beginning of your script:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Adelaide');
```

This can also be used through your script to simulate different timezones.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Adelaide');
echo date("l, F jS, Y",time());

date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
echo date("l, F jS, Y",time());

date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');
echo date("l, F jS, Y",time());
```

This is the easiest way, that will also adjust automatically with daylight savings:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Adelaide');
    $adelaide = time();

    date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
    $melbourne = time();

    date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');
    $sydney = time();

    //etc...

?>

<?=date("l, F jS, Y",$adelaide);?>
```

Comment: Awesome..thankyou what would be best way to create a var for each one like <? php echo $adelaide ?> etc

Comment: `$adelaide = time() + $offset` or `date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Adelaide');$adelaide = time();`. Preferably use the former as `date_default_timezone_set` was designed to set a default timezone once.

Comment: thanks, could you please post the complete php as I am utterly crap with php. Please

Comment: hey @crolpa I keep getting parse errors when i try to do the offset. Do i just wrap them in <? and ?> ???
Also updated question

Comment: I think I left off `;` `<?=date("l, F jS, Y",$adelaide)?>` to `<?=date("l, F jS, Y",$adelaide);?>`. A better practice is to use full tags: `<?php echo date("l, F jS, Y",$adelaide); ?>`. Server time can be outputted with `echo date('r')` (put before setting `date_default_timezone_set`)